Jenkins build erroing out
Need to update the jenkins pipline such that We can add commands on the go : So I am trying to reset the Jenkins build number on a job (as I have many time before) using this groovy code in the script console like
Need to update the jenkins pipline such that We can add commands on the go : So I am trying to reset the Jenkins build number on a job (as I have many time before) using this groovy code in the script console like
Need to update the jenkins pipline such that We can add commands on the go : So I am trying to reset the Jenkins build number on a job (as I have many time before) using this groovy code in the script console like
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'NAMES', defaultValue: 'base-file-name', description: 'Base name for the destination files')
        string(name: 'SOURCE_BUCKET', defaultValue: 'gs://source-bucket-path/', description: 'Source GCS bucket and path')
        string(name: 'DESTINATION_BUCKET', defaultValue: 'gs://destination-bucket-path/', description: 'Destination GCS bucket')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Copy and Rename Files') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        // List files in the source bucket matching the pattern 'part*'
                        def files = sh(script: "gsutil ls ${params.SOURCE_BUCKET}part*", returnStdout: true).trim().split('\n') as List
                        if (files.isEmpty()) {
                            error "No files found in the source bucket at ${params.SOURCE_BUCKET}"
                        }

                        // Total file count, zero-padded
                        def fileCount = files.size().toString().padLeft(5, '0')
                        def successCount = 0
                        def failureCount = 0

                        // Process each file
                        files.each { sourceFile ->
                            try {
                                sourceFile = sourceFile.trim()
                                def fileName = sourceFile.substring(sourceFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
                                def fileNumber = fileName.substring(5, 10) // Extract the "00000" part
                                def destinationFileName = "${params.NAMES}-${fileNumber}-of-${fileCount}-hybrid.avro"
                                def destinationFile = "${params.DESTINATION_BUCKET}${destinationFileName}"

                                // Copy file and log success
                                sh """
                                    gsutil cp ${sourceFile} ${destinationFile}
                                    echo "Copied ${sourceFile} to ${destinationFile}"
                                """
                                successCount++
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                echo "Failed to copy ${sourceFile}: ${e.getMessage()}"
                                failureCount++
                            }
                        }

                        // Final log summary
                        echo "File processing completed. Success: ${successCount}, Failure: ${failureCount}"
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        error "Pipeline failed: ${e.getMessage()}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


fixing the pipeline to suit

"I am trying to reset the Jenkins build number on a job" - huh? Nothing in your script attempts to do that.
